# Munkres Topology -- Solution too straight forward? (S13.5)

Tags: general-topology

Throughout my time studying math, I've generally realized that when an exercise feels "too straightforward" it likely means I've made a jump in my logic and did not justify myself properly. I was asked to prove the following fact:

> Show that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$, then the topology generated by $\mathcal{A}$ equals the intersection of all topologies on $X$ that contain $\mathcal{A}$.

There is also a secondary part to prove this for a subbasis, but I am ignoring it temporarily. My proof is as follows:

> The topology generated by $\mathcal{A}$ (denoted $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}})$ is a topology containing $\mathcal{A}$, and thus $\mathcal{T}_{A} \in \lbrace\mathcal{T}_{i} \mid \mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{T}_{i} \rbrace$. $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}} \subset \mathcal{T}_{i} ~ \forall i$ as $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{T}_{i}$ and topologies are closed under unions and intersections of their elements. It follows then that $\bigcap_{i \in I} \mathcal{T}_{i} = \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}}$

Am I beating myself up for no reason? Self studying this book after I graduated with my degree has me feeling nervous (prepping for grad school and have never taken topology). I also apologize if this question has been asked, I find more people having trouble with the subbasis part.

Comment: Your proof is right, and it is as simple as that. Sometimes (ideally often?) things are indeed straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine and complete IMO.

We could fancify (if that is a word) it a little bit, and add more explanations:

Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the set of all topologies on $X$ that contain $\mathcal{A}$.

It’s clear that $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}} \in \mathscr{T}$ as members of $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}}$ are unions of subfamilies of $\mathcal{A}$ (also unions of singleton subfamilies) and so in particular $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}}$. So trivially, as the intersection of a non-empty family is a subset of each of its members:

$$\bigcap \mathscr{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}}$$

On the other hand, if $\mathcal{T} \in \mathscr{T}$ we know that as topologies are closed under unions, that $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$. As the latter was arbitrary in $\mathscr{T}$ we also have:

$$\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{A}} \subseteq \bigcap \mathscr{T}$$

And these inclusions show the required equality.